# Displaying sqlite3 data into Treeview

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite, treeview

I am writing some code that shows a list of food with their information.

My code:

-connects to data base and gets items successfully

-loops correctly

Problem:

-If the name of my product is one word (ex:eggs) my code displays everything in the correct column

-If the name of my product is two or more words (ex:frosted flakes) my code displays 'frosted' on first column then 'flakes' in next columns which is incorrect

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

def View():
    db = sqlite3.connect("food_data.db")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT name, quantity, expdate FROM food ORDER BY expdate ASC")
    for row in cursor:
        disp=('{0} {1} {2}'.format(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
        tree.insert("",tk.END, values=disp)
    db.close()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x480")
tree = ttk.Treeview(column=("column1","column2","column3"),show='headings')
tree.heading("#1", text="Name")
tree.heading("#2", text="Quantity")
tree.heading("#3", text="Expiration Date")
tree.pack()

b2 = tk.Button(text="view data", command=View)
b2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It is suppose to successfully display items with multiple words in their name onto one column and not carry to the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def View():
    db = sqlite3.connect("food_data.db")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT name, quantity, expdate FROM food ORDER BY expdate ASC")
    for row in cursor:
       # disp=('{0} {1} {2}'.format(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
        tree.insert("",tk.END, values=(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
    db.close()
```

Do it this way rather you have to insert the content in the treeview as `tuple` or `list` after iterating over it.

```
 tree.insert("",tk.END, values=(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
```